# Reloading a UITableView after switching data source through UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UIViewController` that contains a `UISegmentedControl`, and a `UITableViewController`.

The segments indicate directions - i.e. North / South.

The idea is that when one of two segments is touched, the corresponding data is loaded.

`[self.tableView reloadData]` does not work.

The only way I've found to get the data to load properly, is to drag the tableView contents until the current cells are out of focus -- then, the correct data is loaded.

Help is gratefully appreciated.
I am adding the UIDataSource methods for clarity:

```
- (IBAction)segmentAction:(id)sender
{
    //All data is loaded into two arrays in ViewDidLoad.
    [self.tableView reloadData];    
}



#pragma mark - tableView

//Number of sections: 1

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (directionControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) return routeDirection0.count;
    return routeDirection1.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DetailCellIdentifier";

    RouteDetailCell *cell = (RouteDetailCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RouteDetailCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    //currentRoute is an initialized mutable array
    if (self.directionControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        currentRoute = [routeDirection0 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    if (self.directionControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        currentRoute = [routeDirection1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    NSString *tempString = [currentRoute valueForKey:@"Name" ];
    cell.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tempString];
    return cell;
}
```

UPDATE - As requested, I set a breakpoint to check the state of the tableView when the segment control is tapped. One thing I notice is that the frame size is zero..

```
2015-05-18 12:23:10.188 Transit[14488:3166122] -[RouteDirectionViewController segmentAction:]
2015-05-18 12:23:10.189 Transit[14488:3166122] tableView: <UITableView: 0x7f9f6e057200; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7f9f6b44b2d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9f6b44d160>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}>
2015-05-18 12:23:12.494 Transit[14488:3166122] -[RouteDirectionViewController segmentAction:]
2015-05-18 12:23:12.494 Transit[14488:3166122] tableView: <UITableView: 0x7f9f6e057200; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7f9f6b44b2d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9f6b44d160>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}>
```

Comment: Have you verified that your `segmentAction:` method is actually being called?

Comment: Yes, it is. The data refreshes, but only when I drag cells off the screen.

Comment: Is your `numberOfRowsInSection:` being called after `reloadData` is called?

Comment: Did you put in a breakpoint and verify that cellForRow is being called after the segment changes?

Comment: check also  if self.tableView  is connected with IBOutlet in your xib

Comment: @rmaddy -- hmm Number of rows is not being called..

Comment: Is `self.tableView` set properly and not `nil`?

Comment: If I alloc/init tableview, numberOfRows is called, but no cells show

Comment: oops, other way round. if I don't alloc/init, no cells are shown

Comment: @DanieleCandotti - yep there is a connection set in the scene

Comment: @rmaddy - is that what you meant in "Is self.tableView set properly"?

Comment: @DavidDelMonte Set a breakpoint in your `segmentAction:` method. When the breakpoint is hit, look at the value for `self.tableView`. Confirm that it isn't `nil`. If it is `nil`, that explain why the table isn't reloading.

Comment: Will do, but should I init/alloc the tableView or not.

Comment: You have to `alloc/init` the table view if you create the table view through code. If you are adding the table view through IB, then no, you must not.

Comment: I'm editing my question to show the breakpoint log. Note the cell frame is 0? Not sure what to do about this..

Comment: I don't know what to do about this, but the question has been edited, and now shows (first line or two), `UITableViewController`. This is not correct. It is a `UITableView`. I don't have the rep. to edit the post, but I think it's important.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was to create two `UITableViews` and swapping these rather than the data.

All that was involved was:

1. wiring the datasource and delegates to both tableViews.
2. In `numberOfRowsInSection:`, checking which table was being used (based on the segmented control index).
3. Doing the same in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.